# Doing ls -l /dev

Tags: ls

When experimenting with the `ls -l` command I noticed that in the `/dev` folder
`ls -l` was sometimes printing something like this in the first column :

```
crw-rw----+
```

What is this "+"? What does it mean? The man page does not give any information about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This `+` symbol mean that the file has some additional attributes, like ACL

Answer (score 0):

You can check the ACL access given to the directory_name run `getfacl directory_name` to understand the access given to the users.